# PHP Math with dates

Tags: php, math, date

I have no idea why this is not working. The first variable is the number 11 and the second variable is 12 and it comes out as 0. I don't know why, I expect it to output the answer is 1.

```
<?php echo htmlentities(
    date('m', strtotime($resultArray['commissionEligibilityDate'])) -
    date('m', strtotime($resultArray['tiercommissionexpiration']))); ?>
```

Comment: strtotime accepts a string that describes an entire date. date('m') will return the month. date()'s second parameter needs to be a unix timestamp

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Both evaluate to 0!

Comment: trying to take one month and subtract another month

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to get by calling `strtotime(11)` and `strtotime(12)`?

Answer (score 0):

From reading your question, I take it that

- `$resultArray['commissionEligibilityDate'] == 11`
- `$resultArray['tiercommissionexpiration'] == 12`

`strtotime` expects an English date phrase - 11 and 12 are meaningless to it, so it will return false (or -1 on PHP < 5.10)